# hdfs filesystem difference between namenode and datanode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

requesting to please help me in one small query of mine.

1. when we issue hdfs dfs command it will show the filesystem of namenode or datanode. ?
2. how can we see filesystem of namenode and datanode separately?
3. in my project, when i issue hdfs dfs -ls command it shows me files and directories. if i create a file it will create the file by default on it's choice of data node or somewhere else.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

`dfs` commands will communicate with both the namenode and datanode

Namenode has no "filesystem" for listing content - its just metadata in memory. There of course is a local disk directory for a namenode, for checkpointing and backups, but the primary operations are against the memory storage for quick lookup.

A single datanode holds a subset of files called blocks. The namenode maintains the block locations and how files are collectively built from those blocks throughout the cluster

[Persistence of FileSystem Metadata](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#The_Persistence_of_File_System_Metadata)

Creation of HDFS files cannot target specific datanodes, and again, the file is split apart to many datanodes, whose locations are placed into the namenode memory

Comment: Wow.thank u sir. Was struggling to find the ans. Thanks again